# SDL compilation error

Tags: android, c, linux, arm

I am trying to compile SDL from official sdl2-2.0.0 sources . I use GCC 4.7.2 on arm ( android ) and I want to compile it for arm .

I use this configure flags

```
./configure --enable-joystick=no --enable-video=no --enable-audio=no
```

I get error

```
unknown type name "SDL_TLSData"
```

in src/thread/SDL_systhread.h file .